# Nagle algorithm on receiver side

Tags: nagle

I think I understand (but I may be wrong ;-)) the principle of Nagle algorithm on sender side: messages can be delayed by the IP Stack on sender side as long as the previous packet has not been acknowledged.

Nevertheless, if a single packet is sent and contains several applicative messages (Mn, Mn+1, Mn+2 for example), how the receiver is able to split the different applicative messages (Mn, Mn+1, Mn+2) from this single packet ?

Is there any flag in the packet to warn the receiver ?
Is it related with the PSH flag ?
Is it related to Sequence number or Acknowledgment number ? (I don't think so)

Who is in charge of splitting messages on receiver side ?
IP Stack or Application ?
I think it's IP Stack, but is there a standard option to activate ?

Shall the sender and the receiver send a common configuration ? (for example around deactivation of NO_DELAY option ?)

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: _"how the receiver is able to split the different applicative messages (Mn, Mn+1, Mn+2) from this single packet ?"_ - by implementing a framing protocol. TCP doesn't carry messages, it carries bytes. One `send()` does not correspond to one `recv()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer CodeCaster. I know that TCP carry only bytes. I just want to know how the receiver is warned that IP stack on sender side has merged several messages in a single TCP frame ?

Comment: It isn't, you have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Ok, you're right I was no doubt too much focused on the idea that a recv() call is associated with only one applicative message. I also suppose that a tool as Wireshark cannot identify if Nagle algorithm is used or not by the sender (the only symptom is the absence of PSH flag).